# Back button on action bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

when I create a new activity, Android Studio show me this photo:

[image]

It have a Back button but activity haven't it. how can I Make visible it?

Comment: Please post your code. What did you've tried thus far?

Comment: My activity is empty. Nothing came to my mind.

Comment: you may want to read [Add an up action](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action). And about android development in general.
But you could try to override the `onCreate` method of the activity and add `supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` to the method

Answer (score 1):

put `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` into onCreate() method in your activity class

Answer (score 0):

In manifest declare the activity as a parent activity to get this button like this

```
<activity android:name="com.owletogroceries.activity.RewardsActivity"/>

<activity android:name="OrderConfirmationActivity" 
          android:parentActivityName="ProductActivity"/>
```